# tabu: 'Dimension too large' error when using X columns inside longtabu

Tags: xetex, tabu, longtabu

I'm trying to make a multi page table with the `tabu` package. I want to use X columns for some advanced layout, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Below are some minimal examples of what works, and what doesn't.

Example from documentation - WORKS:

```
\begin{tabu} to\linewidth{|X[2]|X[2]|X|X|X[2]|X[2]|} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\end{tabu}
```

`tabu` without X - WORKS:

```
\begin{tabu} to\linewidth{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\end{tabu}
```

`longtabu` without X - WORKS:

```
\begin{longtabu} to\linewidth{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

`longtabu` with X - DOESN'T WORK

```
\begin{longtabu} to\linewidth{|X[2]|X[2]|X|X|X[2]|X[2]|} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

That last snippet of code produces a bunch of `Dimension too large` errors. The documentation states that X columns work inside the `longtabu` environment. All code is running in text mode.

Is there something I've missed?

Comment: `tabu` is outdated and unmaintained. You may use `longtblr` environment in `tabularray` package.

Comment: @L.J.R. does the `tabularray` package include an option to set certain columns in math mode (like `X[$$]` in tabu) or does one have to do that the long way around?

Comment: I am planning to add `X[$$]` to `tabularray` in next month.

Comment: At this time you could use `>{$$}` and `<{$$}` for math columns.

Comment: `tabularray` is too slow, it can increase the build time from 10s to 6min…